# Collapse hamburger menu not visible in bootstrap 4's navbar-inverse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to set my navbar to the inverse colorway; however, navbar-brand and nav-item are showing with the exception of the hamburger menu. When I change it to a navbar-dark, the hamburger menu is visible again. What's the reason for this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse">
    <a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Browse</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Because navbar-inverse changed to navbar-dark after Bootstrap 4 alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 have major changes from bootstrap 3.
I use this to upgrade from BS3 to BS4 http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/
Here's your Bs4 dark navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md"> <a id="logo" class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler"
type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-start" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Browse</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```